# Import yahoo contacts in a gridview in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to import yahoo contacts in my asp.net web application. i got the code from

http://gnillydev.blogspot.com/2007/10/yahoo-contact-import-class-in-c.html

but i am not able to understand how to show  the contacts in gridview with contacts's profile

pic.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Isha

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's not related to yahoo contact, you just need to konw how to display a picture in gridview. Hope this help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479350.aspx